# How to delete files automatically from a NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, automation

There is a **CP Plus NVR** at my organisation which records data from the cameras and stores them in a dedicated **QSAN XCubeNAS Server**.

Our NAS has limited storage, is there a way to automatically delete files from a certain folder/directory every X number of days?

I have looked for options like Scheduler or job into the NAS but I didn't find one. Kindly help me by suggesting an approach to a solution.

Comment: Why don’t you run a cleanup job from an attached client?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a bash script with crontab that can delete files older than specific number of days:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Directory to remove files from
directory="/path/to/your/directory"

days=X

find "$directory" -type f -mtime +$days -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the NAS on a server using CIFS/SMB or NFS protocol, and then you could run a cron job for example with a shell script that cleans the NAS.

Built in is data deduplicalion, that might also help save storage space. Data deduplication is a process that reduces the amount of storage space needed by eliminating duplicate copies of data. Instead of storing multiple identical copies of the same data, deduplication identifies and stores a single copy.